# HTML video element controls not show

Tags: html, html5-video

I create a video element, and set controls = true, but controls not showing (even hover)

```js
if (!this._player) {
    this._player = document.createElement('video');
}

this._player.controls = true;
this._player.src = xxxxx;
```

also set video element width is 100%
the container position is relative

How should I do to show the default video control

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Could you please show some code? A player is usually like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

This may help you:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp